# Number of digits after decimal point in scientific (e) format

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, format, scientific-notation

I want to get desired number of digits after decimal point while keeping answer in scientific format (e.g. 2.989e+10). I know the method format: "{:0.Ae}".format(given_number) where A is number of digits after decimal. However, I'm getting number of digits after the decimal (A) through a variable.
Can someone please help me how can I implement it to get the desired result?
My code: Consider A as number of digits after decimal point.

```
for val in [1.049666666666667e-08, 4.248944444444444e+05]:
    val_log = math.log10(val);
    val_e = round(val_log - (0.5 if val_log<0 else 0));
    A = abs(val_e +3);
    valstr = "{:0.Ae}".format(val)
print(valstr)
```

It is basically number of digits after decimal point(A) = |3 + the value after e|. How should I use value of A in {:0.xe}.format(val) ?

Comment: What is the desired result and what do you currently have?

Comment: For first value I want A = |-8+3| = 5 digits after decimal so it is : 1.04967e-08.
For 2nd value I want A = |5+3| = 8 digits after decimal so it is : 4.24894444e+05
Currently I'm not understanding how to put value of A in the .format()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest a variable in the precision field, as the documentation of [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) points out in an example with the comment "nested fields".

Below is a more simplified example that limits the precision to 3 digits (or 2 digits after the decimal point):

```
>>> f = 123.12345
>>> n = 3
>>> print(f'{f:.{n}}')
1.23e+02
>>>
```

Comment: A question. This one doesn't give the correct format when f = 1.049666666666667e-04 that is when the digits after decimal are between +6 to -4 [6, -4]. It doesn't give exponential notation. Any method by which we can tackle this problem?